# Mule ESB - how to pass multi parameter to soap web service in browser

Tags: web-services, soap, cxf, mule, url-parameters

I just have a little experience with Mule ESB 3.5, and I found that most of Mule examples only create SOAP Web Service with one parameter. For example, you can see that in SOAP Web Service Security example.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/SOAP+Web+Service+Security+Example

So I have one question, acroding to above example,  after using CHOICE flow control, how to pass multi parameter to method of SOAP web service.

Some suggests for me is to use object array to pass multi parameter, but I still have no clue at all.

Thanks to David. I just try your suggestion. But I think I should update my question to make it clearly.

Firstly, I create web service

```
@WebService
public interface Greeter
{
    public String greet(String name);
    public String welcome( String name1,String name2);

}
```

Then I have a control flow for web service configuration

```
<flow name="UnsecureServiceFlow" doc:name="UnsecureServiceFlow">
    <http:inbound-endpoint address="http://localhost:63081/services/unsecure" exchange-pattern="request-response" doc:name="HTTP Inbound Endpoint"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.Greeter" doc:name="Unsecure service"/>
    <component class="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.GreeterService" doc:name="Greeter Service" />
</flow>

Next is the sub flow using jax-ws client to call the method of web service
 <flow name="SecurityClients" doc:name="SecurityClients">
        <http:inbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="63080" path="client" doc:name="HTTP Inbound Endpoint"/>
        <set-payload value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['name']]" doc:name="Set payload with 'name' query param"/>
        <set-variable variableName="clientType" value="#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['clientType']]" doc:name="Set clientType"/>
        <choice doc:name="Choice">
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'unsecure']">
                    <flow-ref name="unsecure" doc:name="Invoke unsecure sub-flow"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'usernameToken']">
                    <flow-ref name="usernameToken" doc:name="Invoke usernameToken sub-flow"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'usernameTokenSigned']">
                    <flow-ref name="usernameTokenSigned" doc:name="Invoke usernameToken Signed sub-flow"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'usernameTokenEncrypted']">
                    <flow-ref name="usernameTokenEncrypted" doc:name="Invoke usernameToken Encrypted sub-flow"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'samlToken']">
                    <flow-ref name="samlToken" doc:name="Invoke samlToken sub-flow"/>
            </when>
            <when expression="#[clientType == 'samlTokenSigned']">
                    <flow-ref name="samlTokenSigned" doc:name="Invoke samlToken Signed sub-flow"/>
            </when>
            <otherwise>
                    <set-payload value="Client type is not supported" doc:name="Client type is not supported"/>
            </otherwise>
        </choice>
        <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/plain" doc:name="Set response Content-Type"/>
        <catch-exception-strategy doc:name="Catch Exception Strategy">
            <set-payload value="There has been an Error processing the request" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
            <set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="text/plain" doc:name="Set response Content-Type"/>
        </catch-exception-strategy>
    </flow>
    <sub-flow name="unsecure" doc:name="unsecure">
        <cxf:jaxws-client operation="greet" serviceClass="com.mulesoft.mule.example.security.Greeter" doc:name="Unsecure SOAP client" doc:description="Unsecure SOAP client"/>
        <http:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" host="localhost" port="63081" path="services/unsecure" doc:name="Invoke unsecure Web Service"/>
    </sub-flow>
```

It's ok to use that address to invoke greet method, it only has one parameter. 
localhost:63080/client?clientType=usernameToken&name=John
However when I change **greet** method to **welcome** method, I do not know how to pass more parameter to it or have to change anything , because **payload** only contains **name** parameter

Comment: Create your WSDL first then generate the JAX-WS infrastructure from it and you'll have a web service that is capable of dealing with complex objects.

Comment: Thank David, however I think you misunderstood me here. In that example, after pass choice flow control, I will invoke one method of web service which was already built, but that method only have one parameter, whereby when I change to another method which has 2 parameters, I don't know how to pass parameters to it. Or may be could you instruct me your method with more detail. Thanks again!

Comment: I don't get it: you want to invoke an already existing web service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate the JAX-WS **client** classes from the remote web service WSDL and use them in a `cxf:jaxws-client` configuration element.

In your case, you need to `set-payload` inside each `when` in order to create the request object that is needed by `cxf:jaxws-client`.

Suppose that you need to create a `org.saml.SamlToken` object for the `samlToken` case, you would do:

```
<set-payload value="#[st=new org.saml.SamlToken();st.field1=message.inboundProperties.field1; ... ; st]" />
```

in the `when` right before `flow-ref`.

PS. You can use `#[message.inboundProperties.clientType]` instead of `#[message.inboundProperties['http.query.params']['clientType']]`

Comment: Thanks again, David. I tried your suggestion, but I just update my answer. Would you help me one more time?

Comment: Cool, I've reviewed my answer accordingly.

Comment: So if I use this address http://localhost:63080/client?clientType=unsecure&param1=1&param2=2 , how can I pass param1 and param2 as parameters to service welcome( String ,String ). If I change service to welcome(NameObject) I can use payload as NameObject container, so that service can run well. But I do not want to change all services to single-parameter service

Comment: In that case the request object is an array of values, i.e. `[String, String]`. Not sure what's the problem with "single-parameter service"? Isn't that the whole idea of Document/Literal services? Aren't following a WSDL-first methodology for creating these services?

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem, David. How to pass an array of values? In my case, I need to execute the web service purely from the URL (for performance testing) and get the output

Comment: Hi, David, I just check again your answer and it was successful. I can call and test web service in url.